# React TypeScript how to bind array to routes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I use standart VisualStudio 2017 ASP.NET Core 2.0 React Template.
I have class `Home` from template:

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

export class Home extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

I need to make `routesData` array and to bind components like `Home` to 'Layout' Routes. Here is my try code:

```
interface RouteDataItem {
    path: string;
    exact: boolean;
    main: () => Element;
}

export const routesData = [
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        main: () => <Home />
    },
    {
        path: '/counter',
        main: () => <Counter />
    },
    {
        path: '/fetchdata',
        main: () => <FetchData />
    }
]

export const routes = <Layout>
    {routesData.map((route, index) => {
        return <Route exact={route.exact} key={index} path={route.path} component={route.main} />;
    }}
</Layout>;
```

How can I do it?
VisualStudio shows me an error `Property "match" is absent in type "{}"`
on this line

```
main: () => <Home />
```

`<Home />` is red underline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add property of `RouteComponentProps` in `<home />` because your home component is useing `RouteComponentProps` as its property

You can see more about `RouteComponentProps` property if you ctrl+click the `RouteComponentProps` in visual studio

Comment: Ok. I understand. `main: (???) => <Home RouteComponentProps={???} />` but what to write on places marked `???`.

Comment: Worked: `main: (match: match<any>, location: H.Location, history: H.History) => <Home match={match} location={location} history={history} /> ` `import * as H from 'history';`

Answer (score 1):

Typescript recognizes the react.fc type without having to pass inside a function.

You just need pass the component name, example:

```
export const Home:React.FC = () => (
<Layout
  footer={false}
>
  Exampĺe
</Layout>
)
```

and Pass the component in route

```
import React from 'react'
import Home from './Home/Home'

interface RouteDataItem {
    path?: string;
    name?: string;
    isProtected?: boolean;
    component?: React.FC;
}

 export const routes: RouteDataItem[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Feed',
    isProtected: true,
    component: Home
  }

]
```

and routing..

```
{routes.map((route) => (
          // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
          <Route path="/" exact={true} component={route.component} />
        ))}
```